# Need find correct syntax with Regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Try to look help. since not expert, need to use regex command in notepad++ to find and replace database variable which is start with 
`<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>` and end it if already have word 'Product Details' 
i tried with this command but it seems wrong 
`^<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>.* ?>`

```
<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description</h2>\n
<div class="ui-box-body">\n
    <div style="max-width: 650.0px;overflow: hidden;font-size: 0;clear: both;">
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-girl-dress-for-women-Babydolls-Chemises-silk-cute-sexy-underwear-slips-lace-sexy-erotic/1436728467.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage0.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-girl-dress-for-women-Babydolls-Chemises-silk-cute-sexy-underwear-slips-lace-sexy-erotic/1436728467.html" title="Sexy costumes girl dress for women Babydolls Chemises silk cute sexy underwear slips lace sexy erotic lingerie hot women WR-14" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Sexy costumes girl dress for women Babydolls Chemises silk cute sexy underwear slips lace sexy erotic lingerie hot women WR-14</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 4.95-4.99</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-kimono-sexy-underwear-women-babydolls-sexy-lingerie-hot-sleepwear-for-women-straps-bathrobe-2/1436614639.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage1.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-kimono-sexy-underwear-women-babydolls-sexy-lingerie-hot-sleepwear-for-women-straps-bathrobe-2/1436614639.html" title="Sexy costumes kimono sexy underwear women babydolls sexy lingerie hot sleepwear for women straps bathrobe 2 piece SP" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Sexy costumes kimono sexy underwear women babydolls sexy lingerie hot sleepwear for women straps bathrobe 2 piece SP</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 9.80-9.83</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wholesale-Sexy-costumes-slips-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-Babydolls-Chemises-silk-sexy-underwear-pajamas-sleepwear-for/1784202839.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage2.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wholesale-Sexy-costumes-slips-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-Babydolls-Chemises-silk-sexy-underwear-pajamas-sleepwear-for/1784202839.html" title="Wholesale Sexy costumes slips lace sexy lingerie hot Babydolls Chemises silk sexy underwear pajamas sleepwear for women WR-4" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Wholesale Sexy costumes slips lace sexy lingerie hot Babydolls Chemises silk sexy underwear pajamas sleepwear for women WR-4</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 4.96-4.99</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fashion-sexy-costumes-slips-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-girl-dress-silk-skirts-sexy-underwear-pajamas-sleepwear/1792153682.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage3.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fashion-sexy-costumes-slips-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-girl-dress-silk-skirts-sexy-underwear-pajamas-sleepwear/1792153682.html" title="Fashion sexy costumes slips lace sexy lingerie hot girl dress silk skirts sexy underwear pajamas sleepwear for women SH-bb" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Fashion sexy costumes slips lace sexy lingerie hot girl dress silk skirts sexy underwear pajamas sleepwear for women SH-bb</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 7.88-7.89</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-slips-sexy-underwear-sexy-lingerie-hot-sleep-dress-skirt-sexy-pajamas-cute-sleep-lounge/1800621993.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage4.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-slips-sexy-underwear-sexy-lingerie-hot-sleep-dress-skirt-sexy-pajamas-cute-sleep-lounge/1800621993.html" title="Sexy costumes slips sexy underwear sexy lingerie hot sleep dress skirt sexy pajamas cute sleep lounge sleepwear for women WR-9" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Sexy costumes slips sexy underwear sexy lingerie hot sleep dress skirt sexy pajamas cute sleep lounge sleepwear for women WR-9</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 8.79-8.80</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Women-s-silicone-antiskid-knee-high-sexy-stocking-black-lace-thigh-high-sexy-stockings-hose-sexy/1441142270.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage5.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Women-s-silicone-antiskid-knee-high-sexy-stocking-black-lace-thigh-high-sexy-stockings-hose-sexy/1441142270.html" title="Women\\''s silicone antiskid knee-high sexy stocking black lace thigh high sexy stockings hose sexy underwear lingerie hot SH-8" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Women\\&#39;s silicone antiskid knee-high sexy stocking black lace thigh high sexy stockings hose sexy underwear lingerie hot SH-8</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 3.95-3.98</em>/pair</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-slips-sexy-lingerie-hot-dress-skirt-sexy-underwear-pajamas-cute-sleep-lounge-sleepwear-for/1890007259.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage6.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Sexy-costumes-slips-sexy-lingerie-hot-dress-skirt-sexy-underwear-pajamas-cute-sleep-lounge-sleepwear-for/1890007259.html" title="Sexy costumes slips sexy lingerie hot dress skirt sexy underwear pajamas cute sleep lounge sleepwear for women WR-17" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Sexy costumes slips sexy lingerie hot dress skirt sexy underwear pajamas cute sleep lounge sleepwear for women WR-17</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 7.85-7.88</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1.0px solid #dedede;vertical-align: top;text-align: left;color: #666666;width: 120.0px;padding: 10.0px 15.0px;margin: 10.0px 10.0px 0 0;word-break: break-all;display: inline-block;">
            <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fashion-sexy-costumes-slips-silk-skirts-sexy-underwear-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-girl-dress-pajamas-sleepwear/2039802175.html" name="productDetailUrl" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width: 120.0px;height: 120.0px;text-align: center;cursor: pointer;">
                <img src="image/data/537412/sexy-lingerie//Sexy-costumes-babydolls-cute-kimono-silk-bathrobes-lace-satin-underwear-sexy-lingerie-sleepwear-pajamas-for-women-LLY-2-descriptionImage7.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;max-width: 120.0px;max-height: 120.0px;border: 0 none;"
                />
            </a><span style="display: block;line-height: 14.0px;height: 28.0px;width: 100.0%;overflow: hidden;margin: 4.0px 0;font-size: 11.0px;"><a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Fashion-sexy-costumes-slips-silk-skirts-sexy-underwear-lace-sexy-lingerie-hot-girl-dress-pajamas-sleepwear/2039802175.html" title="Fashion sexy costumes slips silk skirts sexy underwear lace sexy lingerie hot girl dress  pajamas sleepwear for women WR-31" style="color: #666666;cursor: pointer;" name="productSubject">Fashion sexy costumes slips silk skirts sexy underwear lace sexy lingerie hot girl dress  pajamas sleepwear for women WR-31</a></span>
            <span
            style="color: #999999;font-size: 12.0px;line-height: 1;"><em style="color: #bd1a1d;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;">US $ 8.85-8.88</em>/piece</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
        <h2 style="padding: 5.0px;"> <span style="font-size: 16.0px;"><span style="font-family: \\''comic sans ms\\'';">Product Details
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this regex

```
/<h2 class="ui-box-title">Product Description<\/h2>.+(?=Product Details)/s
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/aF2gO2/1)